# Question about vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V,W$ be real vector spaces and let $L: V \to W$ be a linear function.
 Prove that if $U \subset V$ is a vector subspace then $L(U) \subset W$ is a vector subspace.

What condition is required to have a vector as a subspace to another vector?

Comment: Do you know the Subspace Test?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\def\v#1{{\bf#1}}\v w_1,\v w_2$ be in $L(U)$.  By definition this means
$$\v w_1=L(\v u_1)\ ,\quad \v w_2=L(\v u_2)$$
for some $\v u_1,\v u_2$ in $U$.  Because $L$ is linear we have
$$\v w_1+\v w_2=L(\v u_1+\v u_2)\ ;$$
because $U$ is a subspace of $V$ we have $\v u_1+\v u_2\in U$.  So $\v w_1+\v w_2$ is in $L(U)$.  This proves that $L(U)$ is closed under addition.

There are two more things to prove: one very similar to what I have shown you, the other is extremely easy.

Good luck!